# facebook ios sdk 3.1.1 FBSession completionHandler not removed

Tags: ios, facebook

When I open the Facebook session everything goes fine and the completion block gets called.

```
[FBSession openActiveSessionWithReadPermissions:nil allowLoginUI:allowLoginUI 
completionHandler:^(FBSession *session, FBSessionState state, NSError *error) {
                                             NSLog(@"openSession handler");
                                     }];
```

But later when I ask for extra permissions for example, both completion blocks get called not only the new one.

```
    [FBSession.activeSession reauthorizeWithReadPermissions:
    [NSArray arrayWithObject:@"user_photos"] 
completionHandler:^(FBSession *session, NSError *error) {
                    NSLog(@"reauthorize handler");
                }];
```

Is this a bug or is it supposed to be like this? How can I avoid this behaviour? Is it possible to delete the completion block after the call?

I looked into the Scrumptious sample and the behaviour is exactly the same. When the app asks for publish permissions the publish-completion block gets called and the login block gets called again.

I'm testing on iOS5 and Facebook-ios-sdk 3.1.1

Comment: i'm having the same problem here.

Comment: i would REALLY love to see a solution that effectively overrides this behavior - i have my session management all in one class, and when other classes start requesting read & write permissions, all hell breaks loose and they start executing each others' completion blocks..

Comment: Assertion failure in -[FBSession close], /Users/jacl/src/release/ios-sdk/src/FBSession.m:  I am getting this crash when login like this.. please help

Comment: I'm having the same problem.  It seems like the Facebook SDK is intentionally storing the completion block behind the first execution (judging by the comments in the SDK) - which to me sounds like a very bad design decision.  A stand alone property should be offered for such a behaviour.  A completion block as part of a service call only makes sense as a one time execution block.

Comment: This problem appears to be at least partially fixed in Facebook iOS SDK 3.2.1. `reauthorizeWithReadPermissions:...` is deprecated and the documentation for `requestNewReadPermissions...` explicitly states that its completion handler behaves like a completion handler - not a state change handler as in `openWithCompletionHander...` and other 'open' methods.

Answer (score 5):

From what I could gather from Facebook's documentation in the API, this is an intended behaviour (not good design IMHO but that's another story).

Snippet in the description of the completionHandler param:

> "...the FBSession object will call the block each time the session
>   changes state"

I can't offer you a fix, but I can offer a workaround:

```
// <Your description of why the workaround is needed.
//
// REF: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12751635/facebook-ios-sdk-3-1-1-fbsession-completionhandler-not-removed
//
__block BOOL workaroundOneTimeRunFlag = NO;

[FBSession openActiveSessionWithReadPermissions:nil allowLoginUI:allowLoginUI completionHandler:^(FBSession *session, FBSessionState state, NSError *error)
{
    if (!workaroundOneTimeRunFlag)
    {
        workaroundOneTimeRunFlag = YES;

        // Your handler was executed for the first time
        // Run some code...
    }
}];
```

Comment: It is a solid workaround. Unfortunately all the objects referenced in your code will never be removed because the completion handler will be retained for the lifetime of the app so if anything is particularly heavy you would do good to make the variable __weak. Or you could redefine self as a __weak variable and then pass the results of completion handler into that.

Comment: Yes, very good point.  But as an additional note, the problem you mention is something to be aware of for all possible solutions to this issue (not just this workaround), since the ultimate cause of that is Facebook not releasing the completion block during your app's lifetime.

Answer (score 3):

This is not a bug, and both handlers are intentionally called by the SDK. As noted in the [docs](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/ios/3.1/class/FBSession#openActiveSessionWithReadPermissions%3aallowLoginUI%3acompletionHandler%3a), the handler to the openActiveSession is called whenever a session state change occurs. Asking for extra permissions will change the state to FBSessionStateTokenExtended; therefore, the first handler gets called, and then the explicit handler you provide in the reauthorizeWithReadPermissions:

Comment: OK, thanks a lot! My problem was that I pushed a modal view controller after the openActiveSession method in the completion block without checking first the new state. And when I asked for more permissions the modal view controller was pushed again because the first completion block is called again, which is not what I want. Now everything works great!

Comment: Chris & user - I'm confused on how to handle this properly in my app, and why this would be a feature. If I understand correctly, you're saying that `openActiveSessionWith..` and `reauthorizeWith..` actually save their completion blocks and re-execute them if the session state changes? Is there a way to work around that? I have a central session management class, so the completion blocks are very situational and should not be executed over and over..

Comment: Hey Chris - one more thing, Facebook's initial review suggested this may in fact be a bug; check it:  https://developers.facebook.com/bugs/489654164392251